# Altium: Harness as output of MultiChannel block

Tags: altium

I'm designing a schematic containing a MultiChannel block. I would like to use a Harness with outgoing signals as port. 
If I use a single wire, I get a bus at the output. This is clear. But how can I access the different harnesses?

The picture shows the idea, but is not working!

When compiling the design I get the following error:

> Sheet Symbol with duplicate entries Sheet Entry
>   MEMS1-MEMS_CNT(Passive)

(Repeated for each entity and harness)

[image: This was my idea, but it is not working.]

Comment: Are you using a [harness connector](http://wiki.altium.com/display/ADOH/Schematic+Harness+Connector)?

Comment: Hello Oli, Yes, I use the harness connector in the sub-schematic.

Comment: I know this an old thread, but placing multiple sheets as suggested by Connor Wolf worked! My design: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6m1C.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using harness connections.

Harness connectors seem to be currently incompatible with the automatic repeat functionality of the MultiChannel design tools.

Unfortunately, the only solution seems to be to break your harnesses out into individual wires.

---

Hat-tip to Oli Glaser for reminding me I had this problem in the past too.

My completely baseless guess as to why would be that you can't have harnesses in busses, but I don't honestly know.

Comment: +1 - glad I helped jog your memory :-) Never used them myself, but I wonder if creating the harness textually in the definition file might work (see page 3-12 [here](http://www.altium.com/files/training/Module%203%20-%20Schematic%20Editor%20Basics.pdf) and the section on "How to build a harness without a harness connector [here](http://wiki.altium.com/display/ADOH/Using+Signal+Harnesses) (~3/4 of the way down)

Comment: @OliGlaser - Unfortunately, manually creating harness files wouldn't help much, but only because as-it-is, compiling a project with harnesses automatically generates the textual harness definition files.

Comment: You only need to define them manually if you have a project without harness connectors. On the other hand, harnesses are also useless without said connectors, so I'm stumped as to why anyone would want to do so.

Comment: Ah, I see - just another random guess whilst browsing through the links. When I used Altium, I never had the need for them really, but I can see why they might be useful to keep a very complex schematic tidy.

Comment: OK, It does not work with the Repeat() function. But it is possible to use Multichannel by just placing the sheet symbol several times in the design. the compiler will recognise it and make the same.

Comment: @Botnic - Whoops, I tend to think of multi-channel just as instances of `REPEAT(<x>)` You are correct that it does work with multiple instances of the same schematic page as separate blocks. I updated the answer.