# Multichannel Design - Multiple Rooms not Generating

Tags: altium

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/437963/multichannel-design-with-multiplexers) on multichannel design. I am now in the layout stage and need to figure out why my repeated schematic sheet (Sensors.SchDoc) is not generating multiple rooms.

After enabling Room Generation in the Project Options dialog for *all* my schematics, only one Sensors room generated when I expected eight with the appropriate _SX suffix to be appended to all designators and the appropriate net label applied to connect them to the multiplexer channels.

I suspect that this may be caused by the fact that my eight schematic sheets are no longer generating, despite having them appear back when I was still fixing the schematic. I'm not sure why they are no longer replicating since I've kept my top sheet port and bus naming the same.

[image: SensorsNotReplicating]

Since the eight rooms did not generate, I copied & pasted the original Sensors room seven times. From the pictures below you can see that the components designators did update but no net labels were retained. I plan to route one room and copy & paste the rest but I'll need the net labels in order to connect the output channels to the different data & clock inputs of my MUX. Or am I just supposed to route the first one and manually adjust the output lines to connect to different input channels on the MUX, without net labels?

[image: Rooms Copied]

Here is the original Sensors room, the only one that generated, with the appropriate net labels shown.
[image: NetID]

Here is one of the copied rooms, with no net labels retained.
[image: NoNetsCopied]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. The problem was that I had changed my Net Identifier Scope from Automatic to Global (Project>Project Options>Options>Net Identifier Scope) to fix some other error that I had earlier, so I reset it back to Automatic. Not sure why I did that but hopefully it doesn't come back to haunt me.